# Google Oauth issue while authorization

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

While using the google authorization with Oauth 2.0 (), I am facing issue.

My application redirect URI is

```
http://localhost/google/c.php
```

And I am receiving access_token with get request method from Google, but it send data with following given url (After passing login consent)

```
http://localhost/google/c.php#access_token=ya29.IgCM3ATGrzegCR8AATDlE-cRiYWIUVZhQKCJv6hw2nKTC9jJUYDfDieThjcq8A&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600
```

instead of

```
http://localhost/google/c.php?access_token=ya29.IgCM3ATGrzegCR8AAADlE-cRiYWIUVZhQKCJv6hw2nKTC9jJUYDfDieThjcq8A&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600
```

I do not understand why I am getting # instead of ? before query string of URL.

I am calling the following URL to initiate this authorization process.

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=token&client_id=539024181015-s12j23s8fshbtv0g1n5ajrtml8mheh5c.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost/google/c.php&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get an access token for your server, you should ask for an authorization code and exchange the code for an access_token (possibly w/ a refresh token if you also request offline access_type). Here's the documentation for Google OAuth2 web server flow: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer

Comment: Thanks mengcheng, I got this solved by your suggested approach.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using OAuth 2.0 for Client-side Applications, you are using [Implicit Grant flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2).

The implicit flow is designed for clients implemented in a browser using a scripting language such as JavaScript.

The reason of using hash fragment in implicit flow is that fragment will not be sent in HTTP Request Messages. In this way, access token cannot be intercepted by intermediary servers/routers.

Comment: Thanks Owen, for pointing the issue with my way to get the access_token.